# whole site download manager for Mac?

Tags: mac, download-manager

I am looking for a free download manager for Mac that I can give it the address of a folder on a http or ftp site and it can download the contents of that folder for me. For example a music site that has folder names as the singer names and inside each folder there are mp3 songs of that singer.

Thanks and happy new year.

Comment: You can use *any* FTP client for FTP sites...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[curl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/curl.1.html) 
or
[wget](http://www.renownedmedia.com/blog/install-wget-on-os-x-lion/)

See [CURL to download a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/200426/curl-to-download-a-directory)

For a GUI tool (for FTP) see [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php)

For graphical frontends (GUIs) for curl or wget, you could google for "curl gui mac" or "wget gui mac" (without the quotes) or something similar.

Comment: thanks, will try them.  Is there also any Graphical tool for this?