# How to copy whole directory from a web server

Tags: windows, webserver

How to copy whole directory from a web server.

Comment: wget is what I always use for this kind of stuff [wget recursive download](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download) There's also another question about this http://superuser.com/questions/200426/curl-to-download-a-directory Just be sure that you stay on one domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, a FTP client like FileZilla should do the job fine. Unless you can't connect to the Web server through FTP (like, not having an account, and them blocking anonymous FTP accesses while still allowing people to browse files freely in their browser).

In that case, read this:

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-folder-on-a-website-or-ftp/

This should be exactly what you want. ^.^